# .Net Multithreaded Unzip

Tags: .net, compression

I'm using the DotNetZip library to compress a data stream in a Zip file for storage.
DotNetZip is able to compress multi-threaded, and it's nice & fast.

All of the Libraries I've found are Single Threaded for Decompression.

Is this a shortcoming of the ZIP format in general?
Is there a multi-threaded Unzip function in the .Net world? (With a Stream interface?)

If not.. are there technical reasons why this can't be implemented?

Additional Info:
The data being compressed is SQL Server database backups ~ 30 Gb in size, being streamed from a SQL Server Backup command (VDI) through a ZipOutputStream to a FileStream.

Comment: Are you not saturating disk write with a single thread unzipping?

Comment: Nope. Fast disks in the server. 8 CPU cores in the machine... but during unzip only 1 gets pinned to 100%. Definitely CPU bound.

Comment: Are you reading and writing from\to different spindles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a technical impossibility.

DotNetZip doesn't do multi-threaded decompression because I never implemented it.  MT compression was the priority; I did that. I just haven't bothered to do the MT decompression. Compression is generally a more CPU-intensive and expensive operation than decompression; this is particularly true with DEFLATE, the typical compression algorithm used in ZIP archives, because of the search requirement. Though I am not a compression algorithm expert, I'd guess that a similar characteristic would apply to other compression algorithms. There's no need to search during decompression, and as a result decompression is generally relatively faster. For that reason optimizing decompression in DotNetZip was less of a priority.

---

A side note: the parallel compression in DotNetZIp is done on a single file: suppose you have a file of 1000 blocks (for arbitrary block length).  DotNetZip will enlist multiple threads in compression, each thread compressing one block. Because the compressor threads run independently, it's possible that the compression for block 6 will finish before the compression for block 4, for instance. The main thread therefore is responsible for re-assembling the compressed blocks back into the proper order, and then writing them to the output stream.

In this way, each entry (file) in a zip archive is compressed completely, before the library begins compressing the next entry. There is an obvious opportunity to apply an additional level of parallelism during compression: compressing multiple entries in parallel. DotNetZip doesn't do this now.  This approach to parallelism would make sense when the zipfile being created consists of larger numbers of smaller files, whereas the parallel compression DotNetZip does today, makes sense when the zip archive contains any number of larger files (larger than 512k or so).

Using DotNetZip today, on a typical modern laptop, the CPU gets saturated when compressing large files, those that have more than 10 or so blocks, where the typical block size is 512k. So adding the new level of parallelism wouldn't speed up that scenario at all.  But it would help the scenario of compressing, let's say, 70,000 small files into a single archive.

Answer (score 2):

It is NOT a shortcoming of the format.  The zip format is designed for random access.  There is no technical reason that I can think of that you wouldn't be able to extract multiple files at the same time.  The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) on it is quite detailed on the format.

The only reason I could think of that it would be single threaded in .NET is so that a stream (which is inherently serial in nature) can be decompressed as it comes in.  Obviously that can't be multithreaded to much avail.

Comment: But my thought is that if my original data stream can be compressed on multiple threads and multiplexed into the same "File" during Zipping... might we be able to read the Zip stream and decompress on separate threads, then multiplex into a resulting file?

Comment: It would be possible, but you would need to store the entire stream into a buffer.  The threads could take the task of decompressing certain entries from the central directory, but they would have to have the appropriate section of the stream in order to proceed.  Since decompression is relatively fast, it makes sense to do it on the fly as the stream comes in.  Otherwise you would have to wait until the whole stream came in anyways in order to multithread it.

Comment: La Guardia - not true. You are making assumptions about streaming and decompression. The compressed data is normally organized into segments, which can be decompressed individually.  The approach would be: slurp in a compressed block, then enlist a worker thread to decompress it, while the foreground thread slurps in the next compressed block. This would be directly analogous to the multi-threaded compression approach.  In short: It's possible to do multi-threaded decompression.  I just haven't done it.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible and I believe I did say exactly what you are.  My point is that you don't have random access to a stream unless you buffer all of it.

Comment: Cheeso, thanks for the comment. That was my thinking exactly... I think one of your posts somewhere mentions Zip "Frames" when you implemented the Multi-threaded compression.  DotNetZip rocks, btw. thanks for your work!

Comment: "My point is that you don't have random access to a stream unless you buffer all of it." Bit late to the party but this is false.